# sorting int from a text file in an ascending order

Tags: c++

So i have a text file that looks like this:

```
5
4
9
-3
0
2
```

first int shows how many int their are that need to be ordered in ascending order so the output looks like this:

```
-3
0
2
4
9
```

Im trying to do it without any additional libraries and just use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

So far my code reads the first int but when want it to read the rest it doesnt work. Im still stuck at the reading part.

```
int main()
{
   ifstream input;
   int a,N,i,j;

    int temp;
   // Open the file.
   input.open("test.txt");
    if (!input) {
        cerr << "Could not open the file - '"<< endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
   // Read the numbers of int from the file 
   cout<<"Input fail data"<<endl;
   input>>N;
   cout<<"integers: "<<N<<endl;

    int data[N];
//
   for(i = 0; i << N; i++){
        input>>data[i];
```

P.S. Shoud the rest of the integers be in an array or a linked list?

Comment: `int data[N];` for a non-compile time constant is a non-standard extension to C++. Use `std::vector<int>` instead...

Comment: `i << N` left-shifts i instead of comparing it to N. Left-shifted 0 is 0 is false. So the for-loop never runs.

Comment: Please use the topic of your question in the title, not the topic of the overall task assigned to you. You did not even start sorting anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I tried your code and it worked after some minor changes, which only address the ability for compilation but not the actual approach to read the data. The code considers your restriction to only include `iostream` and `fstream`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("test.txt");
    if (!input) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open the file - '"<< std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Read the numbers of int from the file 
    int N;
    input >> N;
    std::cout << "reading " << N << " integers: " << std::endl;

    int* data = new int[N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        input >> data[i];
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
    }
    delete[] data;
}
```

Maybe there is something wrong in your code beyond the *reading* part.

Comment: I havent even begone whats after the reading part. But as i said above im trying to to this with just #iostream and #fstream

Comment: I just updated the answer to avoid the `std::vector`. It now allocates memory dynamically with the `new` operator.

Comment: When you use `new[]`, you must use `delete[]`.

Comment: You're right, `delete[]` calls the destructor of every object of the array while `delete` only calls the destructor for the first object. Though, it makes no difference in this particular case since it's only integers. Thanks for the hint ;)

Comment: Two things not-so-C++: 1) Use proper RAII where possible; `std::ifstream input( "test.txt" )` would be better than declaring first, initializing second. 2) Do **not** use `new` and / or C arrays unless absolutely, positively necessary. `std::vector` exists for a *very* good reason, and should be preferred in virtually all possible cases. (If this were deep inside an app, and your `for` loop throws, your `delete[]` will never get called and your resource is leaked.)

Comment: @DevSolar 1) You're right, I'll change that. 2) The question was to explicitly avoid any other #includes (including vector), so that is not an option regarding the question. Apart from that, I agree with you in that case as well.

Comment: @J.P.S. {sigh} Missed that one. Why do instructors inflict this on their students, instead of actually *teaching the effin' language*?

Comment: If you are not allowed to use certain includes, you can run it with any include you fancy and use the processed preprocessor output without includes as your .cpp file. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++ doesn't not support VLA:s (*variable length arrays*). Use a `std::vector<int>` instead.

Example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm> // copy_n
#include <cerrno>    // errno
#include <cstring>   // strerror
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>  // istream_iterator
#include <vector>    // vector instead of VLA

int main() {
   std::ifstream input("test.txt");
   if (!input) {
       std::cerr << "Could not open the file: " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   // Read the numbers of int from the file
   int N;
   if (!(input >> N && N > 0)) {
       std::cerr << "invalid number of elements\n";
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   std::vector<int> data(N);  // instead of `int data[N];`

   // copy ints from `input` to `data`:
   std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(input), data.size(), data.begin());
   // or:
   // for(int& val : data) std::cin >> val;

   std::cout << "integers: " << data.size() << '\n';

   // sort them
   std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());

   for (int val : data) std::cout << val << '\n';
}
```

---

If you'd like to do it without the support of `std::vector` etc., you could make a simple container class yourself.

Example:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class arr {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using const_iterator = const value_type*;
    using iterator = value_type*;
    using const_reference = const value_type&;
    using reference = value_type&;

    arr(size_t x) : data(new T[x]), len(x), capacity(x) {}

    // copy ctor
    arr(const arr& rhs) : arr(rhs.len) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) data[i] = rhs.data[i];
    }

    // move ctor
    arr(arr&& rhs) noexcept : data(rhs.data), len(rhs.len), capacity(rhs.capacity) {
        rhs.data = nullptr;
    }

    // copy assignment operator
    arr& operator=(const arr& rhs) {
        if(this == &rhs) return *this;
        if(capacity < rhs.len) {
            delete[]data;
            data = new T[rhs.len];
            capacity = rhs.len;
        }
        len = rhs.len;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) data[i] = rhs.data[i];
        return *this;
    }

    // move assignment operator:
    arr& operator=(arr&& rhs) noexcept {
        if(this == &rhs) return *this;
        delete[] data;
        data = rhs.data;
        rhs.data = nullptr;
        len = rhs.len;
        capacity = rhs.capacity;
        return *this;
    }
    
    // destructor
    ~arr() { delete[] data; }

    size_t size() const { return len; }

    const_reference operator[](size_t idx) const { return data[idx]; }
    reference operator[](size_t idx) { return data[idx]; }

    const_iterator cbegin() const { return data; }
    const_iterator cend() const { return data + len; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return cbegin(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return cend(); }
    iterator begin() { return data; }
    iterator end() { return data + len; }

private:
    T* data;
    size_t len, capacity;
};
```

And using it would be similar to using a VLA:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::ifstream input("test.txt");
    if (!input) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open the file\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Read the numbers of int from the file
    int N;
    if (!(input >> N && N > 0)) {
        std::cerr << "invalid number of elements\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    arr<int> data(N);  // instead of `int data[N];`

    for (int& val : data) std::cin >> val;

    std::cout << "integers: " << N << '\n';

    // implement your own sorting algorithm and use it here

    for (int val : data) std::cout << val << '\n';
}
```